# How to add new data tables to rails app in production without losing data from existing tables

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am quite new to rails, and have managed to build an app and deploy on heroku.

In development (i.e. on localhost), I have successfully added two new tables to the app. I would now like to get the two new tables into production *without* losing data from the existing tables in the production version of the app

So far, my only experience putting new tables into the app is by removing (all) existing tables and replacing them with all the new ones, that is:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL 
heroku run rake db:migrate 
heroku run rake db:seed
```

If I run the above code, it will delete all existing data and insert all the new data.

The best method I can think of is to extract the tables I want to keep, and create a new seed.rb file that seeds the database with this existing data for existing tables, and new data only for the new tables. This sounds like it would work but is a bit clunky.

Is there a better way to add the new tables without losing data from the existing tables?

Answer (score 0):

First;

```
$ rails g migration add_foobar_column_to_my_table
```

This will create a new migration file under db/migrate folder. Open that file and edit according to your needs. For example:

```
class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
  end
end
```

You don't have to delete existing data in order to change your database. That's why many frameworks have something called 'migrations'. Here is the migration document for Rails:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html